# UITableView: Scrolling to the bottom with custom/variable cell heights is inaccurate on the initial scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uitableviewautomaticdimension

**Edit: https://streamable.com/rfym will show it in action. The first time I press Scroll To Bottom, it doesn't get all the way to the bottom. I then manually get all the way to the bottom and quickly scroll all the way back up. Once I press Scroll To Bottom again, it works correctly because it is using the cachedHeights.**

So, I've seen many answers for this, but none of them seem to work for me and I'm pretty sure these doesn't work for many others as well:

**`tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, CGFloat.max), animated: true)`:**

Boom, instantaneously, my tableView disappears.

**`tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.frame.size.height), animated: true)`:**

Inaccurate. It doesn't get all the way to the bottom. Sometimes, it overshoots!

**`tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: self.replies.count - 1, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)`**

Again, like the previous one, this is inaccurate.

**I know why this is inaccurate. What I need is a solution for this...**

Here is a bit of code to run through:

```
class RepliesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var cachedHeights = [Int: CGFloat]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.cachedHeights[indexPath.row] = cell.frame.size.height
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if let height = cachedHeights[indexPath.row] {
            return height
        } else {
            return 113
        }
    }
}
```

Remember, **only the initial scroll to the bottom doesn't go all the way**. If I use my finger to scroll all the way to the bottom, then scroll up to the top and trigger a scroll to the bottom, it will be perfect.

The reason is simple: I will have triggered `tableView.willDisplayCell` on every single cell, which means **all the heights are already cached**. This means `tableView.estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` works perfectly after the initial scroll.

However, if I never scroll to the bottom to cache all the heights and I try to programmatically scroll to the bottom, it won't get there. Why? Because I have the `tableView.estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` return 113.

Some people might argue that I need a more accurate estimate, but I refuse to entertain this thought. My cells can be as small as 50 and as large as 5000. **There is no accurate estimate**.

How do I mitigate this?

Perhaps I need to cache all my heights at a different time? What time is that? I don't want to do any calculations of my own. The beauty of `tableView.willDisplayCell` is that I can cache `cell.frame.size.height` instead of doing my own tedious calculations.

**Edit 2: I have a hilarious solution... which is extremely clunky.. and unacceptable... but technically it works. Appended for amusement.**

```
func scrollToBottom() {
    self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: self.replies.count - 1, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
}

override func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if !atBottom {
        self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, tableView.contentOffset.y + 200), animated: true)
    }
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    atBottom = scrollView.contentOffset.y >= (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)
}
```

Comment: Could I see a GIF of it happening? Just go to makeagif.com.

Comment: @JohnDoe Check my streamable link I included up top or here: https://streamable.com/rfym Notice that the first time I press Scroll To Bottom.. it doesn't go all the way. Then, I manually get to the bottom. When I go back up and press the button again, it successfully goes all the way to the bottom.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing everything when the view appears?

Comment: I asynchronously load my data in from a server, so it gets reloaded whenever it comes in.

Comment: Ok you should go check if eddwinpaz answered the problem. It looks like he's got it.

Comment: @JohnDoe Talking to him in chat. It doesn't work.

Comment: Try and set the estimatedRowHeight to above the average height.

Comment: Doesn't work, it'll just overshoot the last row.

Comment: Could I see your entire class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90461/discussion-between-david-and-john-doe).

Answer (score 0):

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 113.0; // set to whatever your "average" cell height is
```

This way your tableCell will reposition without the inaccuracy you mention

Update: ( Remove this function )

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if let height = cachedHeights[indexPath.row] {
        return height
    } else {
        return 113
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to iterate here for those not in chat, but this doesn't work. :(